# How to use Servlet together with Apache Solr service

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, solr

I'm using Java EE technology for my web application. And I use Apache Solr for my search engine. AFAIK, after I config Solr successfully, Solr is running as a Restful service.

So, under my servlet, I try to call this service as another console application I do before. Here is a sample code is used to get json data from an url:

```
 /** Get Data Fom URL Using GET Method */
    public static String getResponseFromGetRequest(String url) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        /** after prepare for data. prepare for sending */
        try {
            /**
             * HttpResponse is an interface just like HttpGet
             * therefore we can't initialize them
             */
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            return parseHttpResponse(httpResponse);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But the package *org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient* is not available (under tomcat server at least). So, I think maybe there are some problems here. That we cannot call another service in servlet, right? If my guess is true, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I think you want to use the API of Solr in java, in which case you don't need to call solr so directly. Also, the fact that DefaultHttpClient is not available suggests for me that your Deployment Assembly misses the jar that contains the class DefaultHttpClient. Try to help on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brief code on using an API available in java to interact with solr(you don't need to know or care about servlets, httpclients, nothing).

```
HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("your restful url goes here");
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    QueryResponse response = server.query(query);
    List<MyClass> beans = response.getBeans(MyClass.class);
```

`server` should probably be a spring bean, it's the java representation (proxy object) of your running solr server.

`query` is a query to run against the server, configure this to specify what you want from solr.

`response` is the answer to the request.
`beans` are objects which are straight from solr itself (as far as i remember, your solr fields get mapped to the java object's fields by field name, no restrictions at all).

note that `server` has a lot of ways to do simple operations without anything explicit, like `server.addBean(myBean);`

Here is how to get Solrj in maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you don't have maven:

```
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj/4.10.3
```

click on "Download ( JAR )".

Comment: ah. so, we just start solr server. Include solr library to project.  And we can run code as above, right ? Thanks :)

Comment: And those apis are in SolrJ library ? Thanks :)